# Mouse movement over form

Tags: c#, winforms

Im using the below code to [***lock my screen***] when the mouse is moved:

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
   {
        start.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

        start.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        start.Arguments =  @"/c rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation";
        Process.Start(start);
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

But the code is being called and locking my computer before moving the mouse.
Any idea what am i missing here.

*When the mouse happens to be in the same position before the form loads then it locks automatically!*

Comment: Try not locking the machine, but simply putting a breakpoint there so you can investigate.

Comment: It's working for me.  Are you sure you aren't moving your mouse?

Comment: As @CodeCaster suggests, a breakpoint would clarify why your code is called and you could inspect the event args, which might help you figure out what is going on.

Comment: Locking the work station with a mouse move is excessively unpractical.  And will indeed fire without actually moving the mouse, Windows synthesizes fake mouse move messages on a focus change.  A tweak that helps the correct cursor to be shown.  Not that you could see that :)

Comment: By the way your NSFW content will still be displayed after you unlock the desktop. Or isn't this meant to hide stuff from your boss?

Comment: @CodeCaster haha nope its just being over protective so no one would mess around the pc in case i forgot to lock it.